# what is the best video processing programming language?

Tags: java, c++, video-processing

i have 4 digital cams, the distance between every cam is 30 CM, i need a software or a programming library that works on c++ or Java, that can take videos from these 4 cams, and put them in one video showing only one image that is gathered from the 4 cams, any hints would be helpful, Thanks anyway.

Comment: I guess you should ask about the best library or best application, not the best language. Also, for which O/S? And, how do you want to merge or select 4 videos into 1?

Comment: Why don't you just get video editing software? This is like shooting cannons at sparrows ...

Comment: @Jan Kuboschek - There is no such thing as an overkill! :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Pure Data](http://puredata.info/) and [GEM](http://gem.iem.at/).  It has some interesting possibilities, although it might be more than you want to bite off.

Java has the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/), which gives you some decent tools to work with.

Comment: If using Pure Data, then GEM is the standard library for video.  But you can also use http://Gridflow.ca and PDP.  They each are based on their own different premises.  GEM is basically exposing OpenGL to Pure Data, while Gridflow is all about matrix math, mostly for video.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which is an Open Source Computer Vision library for C development.  Once configured, it's relatively easy to use.

Check out [this reference](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=cvgrabframe#cvGrabFrame).  Take a look at the method **cvCaptureFromCAM()** detailed in the reference in order to read frames from a video camera.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use the [GStreamer](http://www.gstreamer.net/) framework for this. I have done similar things with it: combining a video stream, a screen recording and a logo into one combined video.

Programming language options are:

- C: using the API directly. It's not too hard. See the  [documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html).
- Python: bindings to the C API
- [gst-launch](http://www.gstreamer.net/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-checklist-applications.html): a declarative language for quickly setting up a pipeline. Hint: It rocks!
- [Vala](http://live.gnome.org/Vala): scripting language with C# syntax. It never used it so I can't say it it's any good.

Also check out my answer to this question: [How can I tile videos/create a video montage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575705/how-can-i-tile-videos-create-a-video-montage/2020688#2020688)

Answer (score 0):

That is a stereo correspondence problem and one way to merge `n` different images would be using some kind of local features (SIFT, SURF, FAST etc.) In OpenCV library there's SURF detector already implemented. You would probably need to use C or C++ for real time processing.